# Combining TabBar and Navigation Controllers Question

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

In my appDelagate I have a UIViewController called "FrontPage" which is basically a log in screen. Once the login has authenticated it removes itself from the superview and creates a tabbarcontroller, navigationcontroller (inside tabbar), and various UIViewControllers in the NC and on their own in the tab bar. I then push my TabBarVC.view to the windows subView.

It works but I was hoping after I set the windows subview to TabBarVC.view I could release the TabBarViewController to dealloc it and the appdelagate would own the TabBarVC, but when I do it's crashing.

As I'm typing this I'm realizing I never pass the actual TabBarVC, just the view but is there a way to do this?

Also if I completely FUBAR'd this up let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the window's `rootViewController` property to your `UITabBarController` instance similar to this:

```
    // set the tab bar controller as our root view controller    
    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

To clarify, this will add the TabBarController, its view and all of its subviews to the window's view hierarchy for you and I would recommend you use this method for your login view controller as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could make your UITabBarController an `IBOutlet` to the app delegate (or just keep the code you have that generates it). Make it a retained property of the app delegate, synthesize the property, and either create the UITabBarController in the app delegate (`self.tabBarController = ...`) or if you use an xib make the `IBOutlet` connection from the UITabBarController to the app delegate in the xib.

You could add the UITabBarController to the app's window, and then add the FrontPage UIViewController on top of it. Once you remove the FrontPage from the window, the UITabBarController will already be present underneath it.